# hide/unhide all comments in xcode

Tags: xcode, comments

Is there a way to hide/unhide all comments in xcode source files?

This would be very helpful when working with code that has way too many comments added.

Answer (score 7):

You can use fold/unfold to hide/show comments using ⌃⇧⌘↑ and ⌃⇧⌘↓. This is also accessible through View --> Code Folding --> Fold/Unfold Comment Blocks.

Comment: I know about comment folding, but unfortunately it doesn't fold single line comments (//) and the code I'm inheriting has a whole bunch of those, sometimes even for multi line comments.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there's a way to do that.

Comment: ⌥: option, ⌃: control, ⇧: shift

Comment: In Xcode 7.2: **Editor** -> Code Folding -> Fold/Unfold Comment Blocks.

Comment: Apparently this does not work anymore with Swift in my case when using Xcode 7.3 (7D175). Even though the menu item is still selectable (under Editor > Code Folding > Fold/Unfold Comment Blocks), neither the menu item itself nor the shortcut simply does not have an effect. Here is another post where you can see others reporting the same issue as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32573974/1487155

Answer (score 3):

Try: Ctrl + Command + Shift + Left
Or   Ctrl + Command + Left

Comment: The (second) ctrl+cmd+left/right shows/hides inner method ({...}) code. Cool but not what I'm looking for here. First shortcut didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 2):

Surrounding any code with

```
/*   
....code here....  
*/
```

makes that comment into a section that you can fold/unfold.

This works even for blocks of code already commented out with // in long blocks.

Hope this helps someone even though this question is 4 years old!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding a bit on Mish's answer because XCode is very subtle with its UI

As @Mish pointed out, surrounding any code with `/* ... */` makes that code fold/unfold-able just like your `{ ... }` sections.

I haven't had any luck with any of the keyboard shortcuts listed on this answer page yet, but if you *hover* over the left hand side of the `/*...*/` section you'll see the UI change in response to that like so:

[image]

that when clicked will collapse the comments. I for one intend on trying to do all comments with the /*...*/ format from now on.

PS: Note that `/*...*/` comments can be inline with code on either side and still be collapsable.

EDIT: I'm finding that collapsing comments inside of some `{...}` brackets is not working because XCode is collapsing the entire `{}` section instead...

Answer (score 2):

A very easy and practical way to hide all // comments is to change the comments' color to black (or other background editor color you are using, normally dark color) in Xcode preferences.

When you want to see them again, just change color to primitive one, such as green

Answer (score 1):

I'm made a summary , it works for me. It's late but a good flow helps writing good code. for `swift 3-4` only

1. In case where you want to write pseudo code first before actual code, you can write everything into a comment block

   `/* 
   first, use http request
   in the callback, do 
   a.
   b.
   c.
   */`
2. then because you might re-write but the logics are mostly the same, so you might not want to remove the comments, that's fine, but make sure they don't block your view, **so you define a short-cut that conveniently fold/unfold all the comment block into one line**. (That's the best you can do.); Then when you fold them, it looks like this: `/*...`
3. to Define shortcut, go to Xcode => Preference => Key Bindings => `fold comment block`

In my case I use  `alt⇧ctrl{` , `alt⇧ctrl}`

then define it anyway you want, but be careful of conflicts.

It really pays to have pseudo code comments folded

Answer (score 0):

Select the code and comments IN BETWEEN the `/*`  and  `*/`  .
Do NOT select the  `/*`  and  `*/` .  then select Code Folding from Editor menu.  It works for me.  Swift 5, Xcode 12.4