# How can I fold blocks of comments in Swift using Xcode the way I do it in Visual Studio?

Tags: xcode, swift

**Edit: It seems to be a bug which only occurs while *using Xcode in combination with Swift*. In Objective-C it seems to work fine. I sent out a bug report and will post the news from apple.**

I started programming **Swift 2** in Xcode after some time programming C++ in Visual Studio.

But I can't find a proper way to get the comments the way I did them in Visual Studio.

Sometimes I just want to **comment** things out and **don't want to see them** again **until I decide otherwise** so I have free space to think about a new approach to a problem. In this way I'm not distracted and find a better solution much easier. And if I don't find a more suitable solution I can still the use the "backup" within seconds.

**How can I achieve this - which I have done in Visual Studio - in Xcode6 and Xcode7 Beta?**

Here is a Screenshot which illustrates commenting in Visual Studio 2015:

[image: folded]

**I just want these tiny snippets which use one line of code and can easily be opened and uncommented.**

I haven't found a solution for this problem anywhere. I only found some methods which seemed to work in an **older** **version** of Xcode but **not anymore**. Please be so kind and check them in your latest version of Xcode before you post them because I already got some methods which are apparently not longer working.

Comment: Post a screenshot of the showing the area on the left of your comment block and your comment.

Comment: The problem is that you're doing this in Swift, which doesn't fold comments like Objective-C.

Comment: I made a video. Dropbox seems to compress a lot in the browser I guess. The quality is really bad but I guess the problem is recognizable.

Comment: @Rob Is there a similar way which works in Swift?

Comment: No, it looks like this feature is broken in Swift code. Worthy of a [bug report](http://bugreport.apple.com), IMHO. You could do something like `if false { ... }`, which can be collapsed, rather than comment, but that's rather clumsy.

Comment: @Rob Thank you very much!!! This problem was driving me crazy. At least now I'm glad that the problem isn't sitting behind the screen. I don't have a payed developer account yet. Can I still do a bug report?

Comment: I'm not sure. Try it out, and if you can't, let us know and one of us can post it for you.

Comment: Ok I sent out the bug report. I will update this question when I have news from apple.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31116132/how-can-i-make-parts-of-the-source-code-folded-hidden-in-xcode

Answer (score 10):

The folding of comments in both Swift and Objective-C works in Xcode 9, by clicking in the comment and then pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

[image]

For earlier Xcode versions, see my original answer below.

---

In Xcode versions before Xcode 9, comment folding didn't work for Swift, but rather only worked for Objective-C. (And the original question didn't specify the language.) And for it to work with Objective-C in Xcode 8 and earlier, you needed to turn on the code folding option under "Text Editing" in "Preferences":

[image]

(In Xcode 9, code folding is always enabled and this option does not appear in Preferences.)

Then you can collapse the Objective-C comments by pressing <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> (or in Xcode versions prior to 9, you can click in the folding area in the left margin):

[image]

Comment: Ah, it's Swift. It behaves differently re code folding.

Comment: this no longer available in xc >10

Comment: @Matian2049 - The preferences option is no longer available in Xcode 9, but the collapsing of comments now works in both Swift and Objective-C.

Comment: it's quite easy to mis-click in that small space; i disabled the super cool shadow enclosing thing.

Comment: using short cut makes more convenience

Comment: I agree, shortcuts make sense, but the default option+command+left will do it for most users.

Answer (score 5):

Currently (as of Xcode 7.2), you cannot fold Swift source files.

To fold Objective-C comments, you need to use a style of comment that has a begin and end like this:

```
/* Start comment
End comment */
```

Then, on the line where the comment begins, hover your cursor over the tiny column next to the line number, and click the arrow to fold it. Click the arrow again to unfold it.

Comment: yes and to fold/unfold all comments cmd+cntl+shift+left arrow/right arrow

Comment: I still can't do it. I appended some code to show you exactly where my problem is. I can't find a position to click on while I'm hovering over it.

Comment: You might need to turn on the code folding ribbon. Go to preferences, Text Editing, and look for a group with the heading "Show:". Make sure "Code folding ribbon" is checked. I think it might be unchecked by default.

Comment: It's already checked. The only things I can apparently fold are inside curly brackets { }. Is this some kind of limitation?

Comment: Yeah, these are uninformed answers. Comment folding has never worked in Swift source files. It still works in objective-c files, though. Hopefully some day this will be fixed. (Xcode 7.2)

Answer (score 2):

In Swift I solve this problem in such way:

1. Preferences -> Text Editing -> Code folding ribbon: check
2. Comment part of code with `/*..*/`
3. Add the commented code block inside braces `{/*..*/}`
4. Fold the code in braces. It works in Swift.
5. Comment this folded bloсk of code: `/*{..}*/`

Very strange solution but it helps sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Just hover your mouse on the edge of the gutter at the start of the block comment and click the little arrow icon that appears.

[image]

Also pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> will hide all comments and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> will show.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find a point to click on while hovering over it to fold it. I attached some example code which illustrates my problem in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I've reported this to Apple via their Bug Reporter. They've informed me that this was a known issue (actually a duplicate of issue 16188787 - still **open** as of this post).

You can see their response below;

> Apple Developer Relations (05-May-2016 07:33 AM)
>
> Engineering has determined that your bug report is a duplicate of
>   another issue and will be closed.
>
> The open or closed status of the original bug report your issue was
>   duplicated to appears in the yellow "Duplicate of XXXXXXXX" section of
>   the bug reporter user interface. This section appears near the top of
>   the right column's bug detail view just under the bug number, title,
>   state, product and rank.
>
> If you have any questions or concerns, please update your report
>   directly here: http://bugreport.apple.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I'm made a summary , it works for me. It's late but a good flow helps writing good code. for `swift 3-4` only

In case where you want to write pseudo code first before actual code, you can write everything into a comment block

```
/* 
first, use http request
in the callback, do 
a.
b.
c.
*/
```

then because you might re-write but the logics are mostly the same, so you might not want to remove the comments, that's fine, but make sure they don't block your view, command+option+← . (looks like this is the default way of folding them. )
Then when you fold them, it looks like this: `/*...`

In case you don't like the key combo provided by xcode, you can **define a short-cut.**
to Define shortcut, go to Xcode => Preference => Key Bindings => **fold comment block**

In my case I use  **alt⇧ctrl{** , **alt⇧ctrl}**

then define it anyway you want, but be careful of conflicts.

It really pays to have pseudo code comments folded

Comment: Just press command+option+left to collapse comments in Xcode 9. This shortcut is already defined for you.

Comment: but it conflicts with system shortcut.

Comment: What shortcut is that? I have no system shortcut that is command+option+left.

Comment: lol, i'm lazy and defined it to swift screens. you know mac can has multiple screens. and if you are only using right hand to control it, you can stil perform switch screen if it's defined as command+option+left

Comment: I'm only here because you posted a comment on my answer. I'd suggest editing your answer to point out that you only have to go through all of this "create shortcut" stuff if someone defined a system shortcut that conflicts with Xcode's. Your answer might be useful for someone who has done that, but it's misleading for the vast majority of users who can use Xcode's default option+command+left shortcut with no extra work on their part.